# Why does net-ssh-2.6.2 fail its own unit tests?

Tags: ruby, macos, testunit, net-ssh

I've installed ruby (1.9.3) on both my Mac (running OSX 10.8.2) and PC (running Windows 7). I've installed (using "gem install ...") net-ssh, test-unit, mocha, and echoe. The install seems clean (the Mac complains about some Unicode junk in the docs, but I don't care about that).

When I run the unit tests included in the distribution, I get failures and errors. They are different on the Mac and the PC. As far as I know, I have the necessary stuff -- ssh is working, my .ssh directory exists and has both an id_dsa pair and also an id_rsa pair.

I've been connecting to and from my mac using SSH (shells, sftp, scp, etc) for a long time, so I think my SSH stack is working.

Is this a stupid configuration issue, or is something broken in net-ssh/Ruby?

On the Mac, I get the following result from running the net-ssh test suite:

```
tms-mac:test tms$ ruby -Ilib -Itest -rrubygems test_all.rb

*** Mocha deprecation warning: Change `require 'mocha'` to `require 'mocha/setup'`.

Loaded suite test_all
Started
...............................................................................
......................................F
===============================================================================
Failure:
test_for_should_load_all_files_and_translate_to_net_ssh_options(TestConfig)
/Users/tms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/test/test_config.rb:35:in `test_for_should_load_all_files_and_translate_to_net_ssh_options'
     32: 
     33:   def test_for_should_load_all_files_and_translate_to_net_ssh_options
     34:     config = Net::SSH::Config.for("test.host", [config(:exact_match), config(:wild_cards)])
  => 35:     assert_equal 1234, config[:port]
     36:     assert config[:compression]
     37:     assert config[:forward_agent]
     38:     assert_equal %w(~/.ssh/id_dsa), config[:keys]
<1234> expected but was
<nil>

diff:
? 1234
? nil 
===============================================================================
..F
===============================================================================
Failure: <nil> is not true.
test_load_should_parse_equal_sign_delimiters(TestConfig)
/Users/tms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/test/test_config.rb:65:in `test_load_should_parse_equal_sign_delimiters'
     62:   
     63:   def test_load_should_parse_equal_sign_delimiters
     64:     config = Net::SSH::Config.load(config(:eqsign), "test.test")
  => 65:     assert config['compression']
     66:     assert_equal 1234, config['port']
     67:   end
     68: 
===============================================================================
F
===============================================================================
Failure: <nil> is not true.
test_load_with_exact_host_match_should_load_that_section(TestConfig)
/Users/tms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/test/test_config.rb:19:in `test_load_with_exact_host_match_should_load_that_section'
     16: 
     17:   def test_load_with_exact_host_match_should_load_that_section
     18:     config = Net::SSH::Config.load(config(:exact_match), "test.host")
  => 19:     assert config['compression']
     20:     assert config['forwardagent']
     21:     assert_equal 1234, config['port']
     22:   end
===============================================================================
F
===============================================================================
Failure: <nil> is not true.
test_load_with_multiple_hosts(TestConfig)
/Users/tms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/test/test_config.rb:50:in `test_load_with_multiple_hosts'
     47:   
     48:   def test_load_with_multiple_hosts
     49:     config = Net::SSH::Config.load(config(:multihost), "test.host")
  => 50:     assert config['compression']
     51:     assert_equal '2G', config['rekeylimit']
     52:     assert_equal 1980, config['port']
     53:   end
===============================================================================
.F
===============================================================================
Failure:
test_load_with_no_host(TestConfig)
/Users/tms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/test/test_config.rb:44:in `test_load_with_no_host'
     41:   
     42:   def test_load_with_no_host
     43:     config = Net::SSH::Config.load(config(:nohost), "test.host")
  => 44:     assert_equal %w(~/.ssh/id_dsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa), config['identityfile']
     45:     assert_equal 1985, config['port']
     46:   end
     47:   
<["~/.ssh/id_dsa", "~/.ssh/id_rsa"]> expected but was
<nil>

diff:
? ["~/.ssh/id_dsa", "~/.ssh/id_rsa"]
? n         l                       
===============================================================================
F
===============================================================================
Failure: <nil> is not true.
test_load_with_numeric_host(TestConfig)
/Users/tms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/test/test_config.rb:110:in `test_load_with_numeric_host'
     107:   
     108:   def test_load_with_numeric_host
     109:     config = Net::SSH::Config.load(config(:numeric_host), "1234")
  => 110:     assert config['compression']
     111:     assert_equal '2G', config['rekeylimit']
     112:     assert_equal 1980, config['port']
     113:   end
===============================================================================
F
===============================================================================
Failure: <nil> is not true.
test_load_with_plus_sign_hosts(TestConfig)
/Users/tms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/test/test_config.rb:105:in `test_load_with_plus_sign_hosts'
     102:   
     103:   def test_load_with_plus_sign_hosts
     104:     config = Net::SSH::Config.load(config(:host_plus), "test.host")
  => 105:     assert config['compression']
     106:   end
     107:   
     108:   def test_load_with_numeric_host
===============================================================================
F
===============================================================================
Failure:
test_load_with_wild_card_matches_should_load_all_matches_with_first_match_taking_precedence(TestConfig)
/Users/tms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/test/test_config.rb:26:in `test_load_with_wild_card_matches_should_load_all_matches_with_first_match_taking_precedence'
     23: 
     24:   def test_load_with_wild_card_matches_should_load_all_matches_with_first_match_taking_precedence
     25:     config = Net::SSH::Config.load(config(:wild_cards), "test.host")
  => 26:     assert_equal 1234, config['port']
     27:     assert !config['compression']
     28:     assert config['forwardagent']
     29:     assert_equal %w(~/.ssh/id_dsa), config['identityfile']
<1234> expected but was
<nil>

diff:
? 1234
? nil 
===============================================================================
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
..............................E
===============================================================================
Error: test_authenticate_should_continue_if_method_disallowed(Authentication::TestSession)
  NameError: uninitialized constant Net::SSH::Authentication::Methods::None
/Users/tms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/test/authentication/test_session.rb:24:in `test_authenticate_should_continue_if_method_disallowed'
     21: 
     22:       Net::SSH::Authentication::Methods::Publickey.any_instance.expects(:authenticate).with("next service", "username", "password").raises(Net::SSH::Authentication::DisallowedMethod)
     23:       Net::SSH::Authentication::Methods::Hostbased.any_instance.expects(:authenticate).with("next service", "username", "password").returns(true)
  => 24:       Net::SSH::Authentication::Methods::None.any_instance.expects(:authenticate).with("next service", "username", "password").returns(false)
     25: 
     26:       assert session.authenticate("next service", "username", "password")
     27:     end
===============================================================================
.E
===============================================================================
Error: test_authenticate_should_return_false_if_all_auth_methods_fail(Authentication::TestSession)
  NameError: uninitialized constant Net::SSH::Authentication::Methods::None
/Users/tms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/test/authentication/test_session.rb:50:in `test_authenticate_should_return_false_if_all_auth_methods_fail'
     47:       Net::SSH::Authentication::Methods::Hostbased.any_instance.expects(:authenticate).with("next service", "username", "password").returns(false)
     48:       Net::SSH::Authentication::Methods::Password.any_instance.expects(:authenticate).with("next service", "username", "password").returns(false)
     49:       Net::SSH::Authentication::Methods::KeyboardInteractive.any_instance.expects(:authenticate).with("next service", "username", "password").returns(false)
  => 50:       Net::SSH::Authentication::Methods::None.any_instance.expects(:authenticate).with("next service", "username", "password").returns(false)
     51:       
     52:       assert_equal false, session.authenticate("next service", "username", "password")
     53:     end
===============================================================================
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
........................

Finished in 2.89621 seconds.

1923 tests, 6101 assertions, 8 failures, 2 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
99.48% passed

663.97 tests/s, 2106.55 assertions/s
```

Comment: Why run the tests on your own machine?

Comment: Presumably the tests validate my installation (at least, that's what I expect them to do). For example, the reported failures seem to be complaining about how Config is parsing the ssh configuration files.

Comment: @Tom did the answer help you? If so, can you upvote it? Or if not, I'll delete it so it doesn't confuse others.

Comment: Yes, your answer did help a lot. I tried to uprate it, but I'm new to stackoverflow and (so far) lack the 15 reputation points needed to do so.

Comment: Which C compiler did you use when you installed ruby?

Comment: I don't actually remember, I have whatever compiler comes with xdebug. I'm not sure I actually compiled ruby, though. I just downloaded and installed it.